# Eclipse Error Importing All Maven Projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, proxy

After some time of inactivity, I am trying to set up my Java dev environment. I grabbed the latest OpenJDK (14) and Eclipse (2020-06), and it started up fine. Now I try to import an existing Maven project that lives on my local machine and I get:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
Illegal repetition near index 2
${env\.no_proxy}
  ^
```

This is within a work environment where I do have proxy settings on my Mac. I tried from my personal machine with no proxy settings, and this worked fine. I am not sure how to troubleshoot this one.

Comment: Are you trying to import an existing Maven project that is already present in your local dev environment or are you trying to perform the import over a network connection - maybe attempting to retrieve a Maven project from a source code repository (Git, Bitbucket, Subversion, etc.)?

Comment: Edited to clarify, it's a project already on my local machine. I will try to remove the .git directory to see if that is prompting any network calls.

Comment: Please add the pom files...

Comment: @khmarbaise It was with any pom file, even a simple generated one. I think I found the issue, though. Answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

This was simply due to my `~/.m2/settings.xml` had `${env.no_proxy}` in it, and my variables defined in `.zshrc` were not passed in to Eclipse. I went in to `settings.xml` and just hard-coded `<nonProxyHosts>`. I'm not sure how to keep the environment variable definitions in `setting.xml`.